# How to fix ambiguous type on method reference (toString of an Integer)?

Tags: java, java-8

When doing this

```
Stream.of(1, 32, 12, 15, 23).map(Integer::toString);
```

I get an ambiguous type error. Understandably, the compiler can't tell if I mean `toString(int)` or `toString()` from `Integer`.

When not using a method reference, I might have gotten out of this with an explicit cast or write out the generics long hand, **but how can I let the compiler know what I mean here**? What syntax (if any) can I use to make in unambiguous?

Comment: Did you try to change map to mapToInt?

Comment: @chillworld that wouldn't be applicable. we're mapping to strings, _from_ ints.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There is no way to make method references unambiguous; simply said, method references are a feature that is just supported for unambiguous method references only. So you have two solutions:

1. use a lambda expression:

   ```
   Stream.of(1, 32, 12, 15, 23).map(i->Integer.toString(i));
   ```
2. (preferred, at least by me) Use a stream of primitive `int` values when the source consists of primitive `int` values only:

   ```
   IntStream.of(1, 32, 12, 15, 23).mapToObj(Integer::toString);
   ```

   This will use the static `Integer.toString(int)` method for consuming the `int` values.

Answer (score 34):

Since `Integer.toString()` overrides `Object.toString()`, in this particular case you could fix it as follows:

```
Stream.of(1, 32, 12, 15, 23).map(Object::toString);
```

Answer (score 23):

Your main options, using method references, are:

```
Stream.of(1, 32, 12, 15, 23).map(String::valueOf);
IntStream.of(1, 32, 12, 15, 23).mapToObj(Integer::toString);
```

Your current version could mean `i -> i.toString()` or `i -> Integer.toString(i)`.