# Invoking toString via method reference in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference

What am I missing? Why do I have to use `Object::toString` below and not `Integer::toString`? Does it have anything to do with type erasure with generics?

```
Arrays.asList(1,2,3).stream().map(Integer::toString).forEach(System.out::println); //Won't compile

Arrays.asList(1,2,3).stream().map(Object::toString).forEach(System.out::println); //Compiles and runs fine
```

Comment: BTW You can just write `Arrays.asList(1,2,3).forEach(System.out::println);` or `Stream.of(1,2,3).forEach(System.out::println);` or `IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 3).forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix ambigous type on Java8 method reference (toString of an Integer)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21873829/how-to-fix-ambigous-type-on-java8-method-reference-tostring-of-an-integer)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This has nothing to do with type erasure.

Look at the error message :

```
(argument mismatch; invalid method reference
  reference to toString is ambiguous
    both method toString(int) in Integer and method toString() in Integer match)
```

The `Integer` class has two `toString` methods that match the functional interface expected by the `map()` method. One is static with an `int` argument, and the other is the `toString()` method that overrides `Object`'s `toString()`.

The compiler doesn't know if you want to execute this :

```
Arrays.asList(1,2,3).stream().map(i->Integer.toString(i)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

or this :

```
Arrays.asList(1,2,3).stream().map(i->i.toString()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: plus one, well covered.

Comment: You can use `IntStream.of(1, 2, 3).mapToObj(Integer::toString) .forEach(System.out::println);` which is not ambiguous as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21876077/2711488).

Comment: I get a different error message though (and perhaps why I couldn't understand what was going on). The error message that I get (in the IDE) reads - "map (java.util.function.Function<? super java.lang.Integer, ? extends R>) in Stream cannot be applied to (<method reference>)". What can anyone make of that?

Comment: @sat I don't know why you got that error message. I tried your code [here](http://www.compilejava.net/) and got the error mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @sat: if you have a question specific to an IDE you should include the name of the IDE you have used.