# this::methodReference or equivalent in static init block in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference

Just curious:  I've got the following code:

```
@Component
public class GoogleExceptionRetryClassifier implements Classifier<Throwable, Boolean>
{
   private static final Collection<Classifier<Throwable, Boolean>> classifiers = new ArrayList<Classifier<Throwable, Boolean>>();
   static
   {
      classifiers.add((tr) -> classInCauseChain(tr, UnknownHostException.class));
      classifiers.add((tr) -> classInCauseChain(tr, SocketTimeoutException.class));

      //vv--LINE BELOW!!!!--vv
      classifiers.add(GoogleExceptionRetryClassifier::isGoogleHTTP5XXError);
   }

...

}
```

Is there a way on the indicated line to avoid listing the current class?  The method is a static method in the same class as the static initializer block.  I realize I can't do `this::isGoogleHTTP5XXError` because there is no instance yet, but it seems like it would be nice to have something like `::isGoogleHTTP5XXError` that would infer my current class without having to spell it out.  Does this exist?

Comment: No.  Such things were considered, but were rejected as not carrying their weight.

Comment: I would be really useful if we had some alias for the current class. Let's say uppercase `This`. This would be also help with other, non-lambda cases. This would not only shorten the code but also it would work while copying snippets between classes.