# How to Resolve Java Method Reference Ambiguity

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference

Is there a way to get the compiler to choose the static method reference?

This code fails to compile because there are two methods that satisfy this method reference.  Is there a way to hint or cast it so that it resolves the static method reference?

```
public class Number {
  private final int value;

  public Number(int value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public Number add(int x) {
    return operate(Number::add, x);  // <---- compile fail here at Number::add
  }

  private Number operate(BiFunction<Number, Integer, Number> function, int x) {
    return function.apply(this, x);
  }

  public static Number add(Number x, int y) {
    return new Number(x.value + y);
  }

}
```

Comment: You don't call static methods with **(::)** in java, just with **(.)** . So where is the operate declaration?

Comment: Well, `Number::add` *is* ambiguous as both methods have the same functional signature, consuming a `Number` instance and an `int` value. But why on Earth do you use that baroque code structure? What’s the advantage of `return operate(Number::add, x);` over `return add(this, x);`?

Comment: You're passing a method reference as parameter when it's expecting a `BiFunction<Number, Integer, Number> function`

Comment: This example is obviously contrived -- I'm just trying to figure out if there's a way to cast a method reference to resolve the ambiguity.  The example isn't too far fetched, though -- imagine this had subtract and multiply and divide methods, and they were also static methods -- then this would allow you to reuse the static method code.

Comment: Even with the addition of more operations, the reason for the detour through the `operate` method is not clear. And, as the ambiguous method references perfectly demonstrate, these `static` methods and the instance methods are functionality equivalent, so there’s no reason to carry both…

Comment: just use a lambda expression

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no "collision" :)

The issue is that `Number::add` *is ambiguous* (the compiler - the one in eclipse, at least - reports that correctly).

The ambiguous code:

```
BiFunction<Number, Integer, Number> m = Number::add;
```

could either mean:

```
BiFunction<Number, Integer, Number> m = (x,y) -> Number.add(x,y);
```

or:

```
BiFunction<Number, Integer, Number> m = (x,y) -> x.add(y);
```

Comment: is there a way to remove the ambiguity for the compiler - something akin to casting (without having to create a lambda expression)?

Comment: That would be `(x,y) -> Number.add(x,y)`: let me edit the answer

Comment: @prior as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21876077/2711488), no, there is no way. Use a different method (name) or a lambda expression.

Comment: @prior not editing after all: I thought I could show that `(x,y) -> Number.add(x,y)` generates the same instructions as `Number::add` (w/ no ambiguity), but I am unable to. Anyhow, have trust that javac and/or the JIT will treat them the same way